Can we cancel a Bitcoin transaction like an Ethereum transaction with same nonce but higher gas fee?
I need to use BTC transactions to buy some shares. If the shares are full (eg. it only counts on first 100BTC), can my unconfirmed transactions be cancelled? Because even if they are mined later, they are invalid transactions. Can I use RBF or other methods to send a transaction with same input to myself with higher fee rate (but less total transaction fees) just like we do in Ethereum?
I have tried with Electrum to cancel the transaction, but the result was that the new transaction's total fee is higher than the old transaction's total fee, not only the fee_rate is higher.
For example, the origin transaction was 100 fee_rate and cost 10000 sats, the new transaction I use to cancel the original one is set to 120 fee_rate and total cost is 6000 sats, but the transaction sent by Electrum is set to 220 fee_rate and total cost is 11000 sats.
So I can't save money to cancel the transaction, which is the purpose I want to cancel.


Can I use RBF or other methods to send a transaction with same input to myself with higher fee rate (but less total transaction fees) just like we do in Ethereum?

No, you can't. RBF transactions must pay higher total (absolute) transaction fees, and there's no other method.
According to BIP125’s implementation details,


The replacement transaction pays an absolute fee of at least the sum paid by the original transactions.


Therefore, both a higher fee rate (BTC/vbyte) and a higher absolute fee (total BTC) are required.

Thanks! That's what I am looking for.
